# Binding var inside NSPredicate - SwiftUI

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

I am trying to compose a dynamic filter in my Codre Data  filters like this (using SwiftUI):

```
@State var NumberOfRooms: Int
    init(NumberOfRooms: Int) {
        self.NumberOfRooms = NumberOfRooms
    }

    @FetchRequest(entity: Listing.entity(),sortDescriptors:[NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Listing.publishdate, ascending: false),],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "category == %@ AND rooms ", "House", "\($NumberOfRooms)"))
```

In the view i want to modify the value of the variable like this:

```
Text("2")
      .onTapGesture {
       self.NumberOfRooms = 2
       }
```

I get the error at NSPredicate:

> Cannot use instance member '$NumberOfRooms' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

Basically i want to dynamically compose the predicates.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your request inside the init like this.

```
var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Listing>

@State var NumberOfRooms: Int = 10

init(NumberOfRooms: Int) {
    fetchRequest = FetchRequest<BlogIdea>(entity: Listing.entity(),sortDescriptors:[],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "category == %@ AND rooms ", "House", "\(NumberOfRooms)"))
    self.NumberOfRooms = NumberOfRooms
}
```

Comment: i get error: Variable 'self.fetchRequest' used before being initialized

Comment: and: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: Check Updated!!

Comment: now  i get: Cannot find 'NSEntityDescription' in scope

Comment: Pass your entity ```Listing.entity()```

Comment: ok i update it like this:  init(NumberOfRooms: Int) {
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest<Listing>(entity: Listing.entity(),sortDescriptors:[],predicate: NSPredicate(format: "category == %@ AND rooms ", "House", "\(NumberOfRooms)"))
        self.NumberOfRooms = NumberOfRooms
    }

Comment: Now i get: Variable 'self.results' used before being initialized

Comment: Also: Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties

Comment: i have two variables:    (var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Listing>) for Json and
    (var results : FetchedResults<Listing>) for Core Data

Comment: Please read this article, you can get more idea : https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/dynamically-filtering-fetchrequest-with-swiftui